# How to know the point exist on the path in Google maps?

Tags: google-maps, cordova, mobile-application

I am developing a simple mobile app using phonegap and google maps. Now I have one requirement where I have to know whether a particular point/marker exists on/nearby the path drawn by google map api. Please guide me on how to determine this.

Thanks.

Comment: [`google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly)

Comment: I am trying with that now.